# Avoiding spaghetti code while writing small functions

Tags: function, coding-style, refactoring, abstraction

My understanding of "Spaghetti Code" is a code base that jumps from one block of code to another without an logical and legible purpose. The most common offender seems to be the GOTO statement.

I'm currently reading/referencing the function chapter of Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship. The author, while self admittedly, is extremely strict on the size of functions. I understand the idea of keeping functions small, however, he suggests they should be around 5 lines. While Classes certainly become more legible, I'm afraid of creating spaghetti code by writing smaller functions. Smaller functions also seem to inadvertently create much higher abstractions as well.

At what point does code become spaghetti code? How abstract is *too* abstract? Any answers would be greatly helpful.

As an aside, I'm a long time follower of Stack Overflow although this is my first time posting a question, so any suggestions regarding my post are welcome as well.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This would probably be better on the Programmers Exchange instead of stack. I will up vote you though bc youre about to get downvoted to hell.

Comment: The author gave you a rule of thumb. However, there is no hard rule. You could be dealing with an algorithm that requires more than 5 lines. However, when you see yourself either repeating code or unable to reuse existing functionality,  it's time go refactor and probably split some functions apart.

Comment: @AMR thanks for the up vote. After looking at Programmers Exchange, I must agree with you. This is definitely more of a conceptual question. I apologize for not making out the difference beforehand.

Comment: @Tarik, thanks for the reply. "There is not hard rule" is quickly becoming obvious to me as I go through these kinds of books. Thank you for the advice, I'll keep reuse and repetition in mind.

Comment: When would you consider code being too abstract? For instance, how many levels in a hierarchy of one method to the next or one class to the next?

Comment: In life, you always deal with tradeoffs. You can design your application with reuse in mind and create a complex API to ensure that no matter what, you can easily plug-in the next case. That costs more time to design and implement. It's difficult to convince your manager that you are doing work, yet not delivering that simple app quickly. On the other extreme, you write a monolithic piece of code that does the job but is difficult to change. Your manager is happpy, you got that piece of software out in no time. Yet when it's time to modify it or add functionality, it becomes harder and harder.

Comment: @Tarik talk about hitting the nail on the head! We definitely have to find a balance balance between deadlines and well-written software. You coincidently answered another doubt that I had after writing my question. I guess the company may be different but the developers seem to have similar experiences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already said in the comments, there is no absolute rule. At the end, you should aim for a good readability of your code. But that is not all about the length of your methods. Robert Martin suggests ordering the methods according to the degree of abstraction. Abststract methods should be at the top of your class, and the more a method is, the deeper it should be located.

Another importand aspect is the method name. It should be chosen well in order to make clear what the method does! If you choose your method names wisely, then comments should be hardly necessary. For example, consider an if-statement:

```
if(isValidAge(value)) {
   ...
}
```

is much more readable than

```
if(value > 10 && value < 99) {
   ...
}
```

because the intention of the statement becomes much clearer. Of cause you could add a comment in the second example. But comments often become outdated (there is an extra chapter in Robert Martin's book about that). I think, this style of programming leads to many short methods.

It is hard to choose the right level of abstraction. According to my expecience, it is easier to start with a low level of abstraction. So I can first concentrate on solving the problem well. When I need more abstraction later, I still can refactor the code. TDD helps a lot!

Hope, this helps ...

Comment: Strongly agree with the last paragraph!

Comment: Hauptmann, thank you for your answer. I agree with @Tarik that your last paragraph really lays out how to work with different levels of abstraction. Most of my projects current only have low-level abstractions and you helped me with how raise my abstractions. Especially with your reference to TDD. Completely agree with you. How do you think I can avoid the cursed spaghetti code while abstracting?

Comment: First of all, every class should have only one responsibility. Classes with many responibilities force the reader to switch contexts often (have a look at @utnapistim's answer). Second, try to keep the public interface and the number of dependencies small. That means, you should use private methods. So your class is easy to understand from the outside perspective. I think of this like a firewall: the class fulfils its contract, and I can test against it - no matter what it looks inside. Having a good set of tests, you can improve the inner stucture until it meets your aesthetic sense.

Comment: I chose this as the most appropriate answer because it provided a solutions to avoiding spaghetti code via well-defined classes with only required outside access. Although I would like to say that utnapistim's answer also helped me understand how to avoid spaghetti code.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with comments and answers here. From practical point of view the thinks which Robert Martin writes in his books are every time very good orientations and I try to get as much close as possible to this "rules" and indeed 5-lines-methodes are mostly not to bad.

In my eyes best way to avoid spaghetti code is to write (small) classes with a high [Cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29). The disadvantage is that you become a whole bunch of classes, which makes it sometimes a little bit more hard for new employees to come in the project.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Cohesion. This is kind of my concern: creating small classes that make one class more readable but harder to maintain by co-workers. Though comments would go a long way in explaining the purpose of classes and functions. Hot keys in IDEs also help developers jump around a project fairly quickly, such as Command + Left Mouse Click on a class or method will bring you to its original context in Xcode and Eclipse. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand the idea of keeping functions small, however, he suggests they should be around 5 lines.

That sounds ideal :)

> While Classes certainly become more legible, I'm afraid of creating spaghetti code by writing smaller functions.

Spaghetti code is caused by code jumping from place to place with (having different levels of abstraction in the same function - low-level IO code and high level application logic). If you extract small functions, your result is getting further away from spaghetti code, not closer).

> At what point does code become spaghetti code?

When the code forces you (the programmer) to make mental jumps (switch contexts) from line to line, the code is spaghetti code. This is true whether you use GOTOs or not (but GOTOs can make the problem much worse).